# C# - bootstrap Modal not launching on click event

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a view I'm trying to display in a modal after the user clicks a button.

I've used this code in an isolated application with success:

```
<a @*id="listed"*@ class="btn btn-primary" id="modalEdit" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Edit</a>

            <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" >

                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <div class="modal-title">Edit Notification</div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            @{
                                Html.RenderAction("Edit");
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

When I use this identical code in my application however, the modal does not open upon button click. ***Note:*** the modal button is located between `<td>` elements in my application. The methods I have tried are as follows:

1. **jQuery Method #1**

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modalEdit').click(function () {
       $('#editModal').modal({
           show: true,
           closeOnEscape: true
       });
     });
   });
   ```
2. **jQuery Method #2**

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#modalEdit').on("click", function () {
       $('#editModal').modal('show')
     });
    });
   ```
3. **Restore default bootstrap.css file:**

I edited this file to override some default bootstrap and thought maybe these customization's were interrupting the default bootstrap modal code but, I restored these defaults and still no success.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: @MattSpinks no errors in the console

Comment: Did you check if the event is triggered (i.e. put some `alert()` inside the `function() { }` stuff)? BTW: The second example code is missing a ';' after the statement...

Comment: @StephenReindl I ended up scrapping the jquery and bootstrap. Built it from scratch with pure css